# Menu with anchor links to sections of a page (#) redirect to another page within the site (WordPress)

Tags: html, wordpress, anchor, elementor

I've encountered a problem that never happened to me before: on this test site: http://c2040213.ferozo.com/dimi/ whenever you click on one of the sub menu links from the "Vender" menu item, they start redirecting to the "Comprar", even though on the href there is no indicator that the link itself redirects to that site, instead, they are anchor links to http://c2040213.ferozo.com/dimi/#tasa for example.

So I'm having trouble discovering why when I click a link that goes to http://c2040213.ferozo.com/dimi/#tasa, redirects me to http://c2040213.ferozo.com/dimi/comprar

I'm working on the latest version of WordPress and with Elementor.

Thanks a lot in advance, feel free to ask for more information if needed.

Comment: Website down for me.

Comment: @Anatole check it now! It's working fine for me. Thanks in advance.